# Adding Value from database to pre-fill form

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
{{Form::label('listing', 'Price:')}}
{{Form::text('price','' , ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Price'])}}
```

I would like to pre-fill the form with value `{{listing->price}}` from the database

```
{{Form::label('listing', 'Price:')}}
{{Form::text('price','{{listing->price}}' , ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Price'])}}

ERROR: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ')'
```

Is this a good fix? Setting a variable and parsing it in

```
$f = ($listing->price);
echo('{{Form::text('price',.$f. , ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Price'])}}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape your quotes:

```
    echo '{{Form::text(\'price\','.$f.' , [\'class\' => \'form-control\', \'placeholder\' => \'Price\'])}}';
```